# How to do Matrix Math operations using arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, visual-studio-2017, matrix-multiplication

I have a homework problem that requires using 4x4 matrices stored in arrays (with values input by the user), and I'm supposed to do a few different mathematical operations on them, as well as being able to display and transpose them. I'm having a hard time with logic for matrix addition and multiplication, specifically, how I select specific indexes in the matrices to do the operations on. I'm also having a hard time figuring out how to display matrices, which is why my displayMatrix function is blank. I'm also struggling to figure out how to store my user input in different matrices in my for loop.

I'm not entirely sure how exactly to make the code that I have work for me, and would appreciate any solutions or other advise anyone has for my code!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

const int SIZE = 4;
const int SLICES = 25;

void addMatrices(int matrix1[][SIZE], int matrix2[][SIZE], int result[][SIZE], 
    int matricesUsed, string prompt);
void displayMatrix(int matrix1[][SIZE], int result[][SIZE]);

int main()
{
    int matrix1[SIZE];
    int matricesUsed = 0;

    string prompt = "Enter the number of matrices you want to use (between 1 & 25): ";
    int initialMatrices;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> initialMatrices;

    if (initialMatrices <= 0 || initialMatrices > 25)
    {
        cout << "Invalid number of matrices. Please enter a number between 1 and 25." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number of matrices you want to use (between 1 & 25): ";
        cin >> initialMatrices;
    }

    matricesUsed = initialMatrices - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < initialMatrices; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the value for position " << i + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> matrix1[i];
        }
    }
    matricesUsed++;
void addMatrices(int matrix1[][SIZE], int matrix2[][SIZE], int result[][SIZE], int matricesUsed, string prompt)
{
    int firstIndex = getIndex(matricesUsed, prompt);
    int firstIndex = getIndex(matricesUsed, prompt);
    addMatrices(matrix1[], matrix[], result[matricesUsed]);
    displayMatrix(matrix[matricesUsed]);
    matricesUsed++; 
}
void displayMatrix()
{

}
```

The expected output is a 4x4 matrix that has received the user-specified operator (I left out that part of the code because it's working fine, but please let me know if I need to upload it as well!).

The output of the program should look like this:

```
How many initial matrices? 2
Enter matrix 1:
 Row 1? 2 4 0 1
 Row 2? 3 0 1 2
 Row 3? 1 0 1 -1
 Row 4? 0 1 2 0
Enter matrix 2:
 Row 1? 1 0 0 0
 Row 2? 0 1 0 0
 Row 3? 0 0 1 0
 Row 4? 0 0 0 1
Operation? +
First matrix for +? 1
Second matrix for +? 2
Result is matrix 3:
 Row 1: 3 4 0 1
 Row 2: 3 1 1 2
 Row 3: 1 0 2 -1
 Row 4: 0 1 2 1
```

Comment: The first mistake -- you cannot have functions within functions.

Comment: It seems that many undefined variables have been used. You should follow the rules of C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use the double loop to traverse the output matrix.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int matrix_1[4][4];
    cout << "Please enter the value of the matrix:" << endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix_1[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("The matrix_1 is:\n");
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%8d", matrix_1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    int matrix_2[4][4];
    cout << "Please enter the value of the matrix:" << endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix_2[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("The matrix_2 is:\n");
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%8d", matrix_2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int matrix_3[4][4];
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            matrix_3[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "operation:*" << endl;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) //The number of rows in matrix 1 is 4.
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)//The number of columns in matrix 2 is 4.
        {   
            for (auto k = 0; k < 4; k++) //The number of columns in matrix 1 is 4.
            {
                matrix_3[i][j] += matrix_1[i][k] * matrix_2[k][j];
            }

        }
    }
    cout << "The value of the output matrix:" << endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%8d", matrix_3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    int matrix_4[4][4];
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            matrix_4[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "operation:+" << endl;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            matrix_4[i][j] += matrix_1[i][j] + matrix_2[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "The value of the output matrix:" << endl;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%8d", matrix_4[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have re-edited the code based on how the matrix multiplication works.